# How to detect if a script exports something when loaded?

Tags: node.js, module.exports

Assuming I have a script 'helpers.js' in the same directory
as 'main.js', and load the first in the latter, 'helpers.js'
will return an empty object `{}` when not exporting anything,
no matter what the content is, which is a default value for
the `module.exports` variable, I guess.

Is there a way to check, if the empty object was intentionally
exported by 'helpers.js'?

Example 1, no export:

```
// helpers.js

// Any valid Javascript here, just no exports.



// main.js

const help = require('./helpers')

console.log(help)

>>> {}
```

Example 2, with export:

```
// helpers.js

let exportMe = require('./you').getNewestMe

module.exports = exportMe()



// main.js

const help = require('./helpers')

console.log(help)

>>> {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had something different in mind but I realized that my original solution wouldn't work, so let's see...

When a CommonJS module is loaded (i.e. `require`d for the first time), Node.js runs a special function - a loader. The loader function has access to the state of a module before it is actually loaded, so it can inspect and modify the original values of some properties of a module like `module.exports`. The idea is that if we can somehow mark that original value, we can distinguish it from an empty object assigned later while the module was being loaded.

The loader function can be retrieved and changed with `Module._extensions['.js']` where `Module` is the module constructor, i.e. `require('module')` or `module.constructor`.(`Module._extensions` is *not* the same as the deprecated [`require.extensions`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requireextensions), but that's another story...).

The loader function is invoked with two arguments: the `module` object and the `filename`. Then the original `exports` object is unsurprisingly, `module.exports`.
In the code below, I'm going to use a symbol to mark the original empty `exports` object:

```js
const noExports = Symbol('no exports');
const extensions = module.constructor._extensions;
const jsLoader = extensions['.js'];
extensions['.js'] = (module, filename) => {
    module.exports[noExports] = filename;
    jsLoader(module, filename);
};

const help1 = require('./helpers-without-exports.js');
const help2 = require('./helpers-with-empty-exports.js');

console.log(noExports in help1); // true
console.log(noExports in help2); // false
```

This method only works for modules that are loaded after the loader function is patched, and it only determines if `module.exports` is changed after the module is created, so it does not detect values exported with `exports.myFunction = ...` (in which case the exported object would be non-empty anyway).

Another special case is a module that re-exports another module that does not export anything (e.g. `module.exports = require('./foo');` where foo.js is an empty file). To detect those cases too, if necessary, one could compare the value of the symbol property with the module filename assigned to the symbol, and see if they match:

```js
console.log(help1[noExports] === require.resolve('./helpers-without-exports.js')); // true
console.log(help2[noExports] === require.resolve('./helpers-with-empty-exports.js')); // false
```

Comment: I'm likely to include your solution in a 'lil package of mine, is it ok, if I mention you in the README as the contributor of that solution?

Comment: @Ida That's fine for me. Good luck with your 'lil package!

Comment: module.constructor._extensions is undefined. How did you get this to work?

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier [Of course it is defined](https://runkit.com/62de229cb825a40009b285a7/62de229c5e2dd100081f115b), maybe check your setup.

Comment: So, turns out that’s not a “public” API, so the typescript node module definitions do not include this property. This is not one to be used  in a TS file is all.